# Pigeon hole set of integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If we are given a set of n integers $x_1, x_2, ... , x_n$,  Prove that there exist indices s and t (where $1 \leq s\leq t \leq n$) such that $$\sum_{i=s}^tx_i = 0 \mod n$$

I know that I should have two sets and a function mapping one set onto the other, but I'm having trouble finding what the sets and function are..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose not, then all the numbers $x_1, x_1 + x_2, x_1+x_2+x_3, \dots , x_1 + \dots + x_n$ have non zero remainder, this means that mod $n$ their residues are one of $(1,2, \dots, n-1)$, but we have $n$ elements, so by the pigenhole principle, at least two have the same residue $\bmod (n)$, so there is two sums $$a = x_1 +\dots +x_k  \quad \text{ and } \quad b= x_1 +\dots +x_j$$
With the same residue, if $k > j$, we conclude that

$$ a - b \equiv x_{k-l} + \dots x_k\equiv 0 \bmod (n) $$

Comment: do you mean if k > j?

Comment: @user2980566 yes!

Comment: Thanks! sorry one last thing could you explain  what your two last lines mean? Like we have two sums a = ... and b = ... and we can conclude a - b = 0 mod n? And in the case of my original question would k = s and j = t?

Comment: @user2980566 they have the same residue (or remainder) when divided by n, this means that $a = tn + r$ and $b = hn + r$ which gives that $a - b = n(t-h)$.

Comment: so would k = t and j = s in the original question?

Comment: @user2980566 No, $t  = k$ and $s = k-j$